# npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install, npm-request

I'm installing express on disk D:/  but I found an error when I installed it, but if I install express on disk C:/  it worked and I reinstalled it on disk E:/ and D:/ Errors like this appear.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAWKN.png)

Comment: Have you tried running `npm init -y` first to initialise a project in that directory?

Comment: not before now it's been solved., thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running into a permissions issue. one thing that I always do is use:

```
sudo
```

that is on Mac. On Windows, you should be able to use:

```
--force at the end of your statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

for windows :
I tried to fix this problem by updating the node.js and installing express globally by running following command:-
`npm i -g express`