# permission error while installing npm packages

Tags: npm, permissions, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path H:\
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'H:\'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'H:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'H:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.`
```

I am getting this error while trying to make a next project and installing express please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637702/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-mkdir)

Comment: Please post some code!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to run the command as a super user, say if your command was `npm install` you would type this command into your terminal

```bash
sudo npm install
```

Notice how you add `sudo` to the front of the command to tell the computer to run this with extra permissions.

You can learn more about sudo by reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)